# Actions on Google number genie - assistant not defined

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google

I'm attempting the number genie example from https://developers.google.com/actions/apiai/tutorials/number-genie and I'm getting the following error when I run the code. It's the section upto Test Your Action. If I comment it out then it starts fine.

```
/home/pi/numbergenie/app.js:54
assistant.handleRequest(actionMap);

ReferenceError: assistant is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/numbergenie/app.js:54:1)
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you update the question to include the code you have that is producing the error (so we know exactly which line 54 is)?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're running the whole code?

From the tutorial I can see that assistant is defined in this section:

```
    app.post('/', function (request, response) {
  console.log('headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  const assistant = new Assistant({request: request, response: response});
  response.sendStatus(200); // OK
});
```

So the code that uses this variable should be in this block too. Hope it helps.